# Display fields dynamically in EXTJS

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I am trying to display a set of questions on the application employee profile (ExtJS 4.2.3) screen, and the answers to these questions will be options (radio buttons say - Yes/No/NA). The issue I am facing is that I need to fetch these questions from the database, and populate these questions & radio buttons dynamically.

Once the user selects the answers to these questions for a particular employee, we also need to save these questions (FK) and the answers to those questions against the employee.

A static representation would be as shown in image. I am new to ExtJS and facing issues to identify, which component (like a fieldcontainer) should I use, how to dynamically populate multiple values, and then while saving, how to pass these values back to the database.[image: Sample]

Comment: Why are you trying to do all in a single phase?   Did you first do this static without database.

Comment: I have employee specific questions saved in database, which i would need to display on the screen when employee is selected or looked up. I currently implement this by using a panel and adding items to the panel, after which I did a panel.doLayout(). THe sample image is just a static one.